# haskell cabal sandbox how to install packages?

Tags: haskell, sandbox, cabal

I wish if someone tells me the steps required to install `gloss-examples` in a sandbox along with all its dependencies.
Here is what I tried to do:

I downloaded the `gloss-examples` package from [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-examples-1.9.4.1/gloss-examples-1.9.4.1.tar.gz).

When I ran the command, after changing into the `~/gloss/gloss-examples-1.9.4.1`

```
~/gloss/gloss-examples-1.9.4.1$cabal sandbox init
```

it succeeded, so I issued the command

```
~/gloss/gloss-examples-1.9.4.1$cabal install --only-dependencies
```

but then I got the following errors:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: gloss-examples-1.9.4.1 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of gloss-examples-1.9.4.1)
rejecting: base-4.5.0.0/installed-c8e... (conflict: gloss-examples =>
base==4.8.*)
rejecting: base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1,
base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0,
base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2,
base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2,
base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed
instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
```

How do I install this package `gloss-examples` and all its dependencies in the sandbox directory only? I think I understand that cabal sandbox allows you to install any arbitrary package with all dependencies (some or all them conflicting with globally installed packages) installed in a separate directory. 
Is this even possible?
I think I am missing something. Is this a right use-case for cabal sandbox?
Seeing the following

`Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent dependencies.`

Is there a difference between `conflicting dependencies` and `not consistent dependencies`?

I tried many tutorials including [this](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html) but could not understand how to use cabal sandbox.

Comment: What version of GHC are you running?

Comment: You don't need to download a tarball from Hackage to install packages in a sandbox. Just do `cabal sandbox init` to create the sandbox and then `cabal install gloss-examples` (or whatever else you want) from the same directory.

Comment: @duplode, from the fact that they want an examples package, I guessed they may want to set up a sandbox for dependencies and then build the package with various modifications rather than installing it.

Comment: @dfeuer Yup, that makes sense.

Comment: I am using GHC 7-4.1

Comment: That is a pretty old version. The latest version is 7.10.2. You should probably upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you have downloaded a version of `gloss-examples` that is not compatible with your version of the `base` library. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Download a version (presumably an older one) that is compatible with your `base` library. [The contents page for the package on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-examples) has a long list of available versions near the top. It may also be possible to use `cabal fetch` to do this—I'm not sure.
2. Upgrade GHC to get a newer `base`. You generally cannot upgrade `base` without upgrading GHC.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the `base` dependency. Is it only `base` or what other dependencies are hardwired in GHC?

Comment: @mntk123, I'm not entirely sure. `base` isn't actually completely hard-wired, I don't think, but it's pretty tightly tied in&mdash;it depends on enough subtle details that it's highly unlikely that two major versions of `base` will each work with any given major version of GHC (e.g., base 4.7 goes with GHC 7.8; base 4.8 goes with GHC 7.10), and there could even be problems between minor versions. The most hard-wired package is `ghc-prim`, which should be seen as *part* of the compiler.

Comment: The `containers` package is pretty tightly tied in too, at least for some purposes, because the `ghc` package (yep, that's also pretty tight) exposes some compiler structures as containers (as I understand it). There may be others.