# Which packages are hardwired into GHC?

Tags: haskell, sandbox, ghc, cabal

While trying out the `cabal sandbox` I found that you cannot install different versions of `base` and some other packages in sandbox as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32724583/4725700).

I wonder which packages are hardwired into GHC. Is there a complete list somewhere?
I could not find it using google.
I don't just want to get the list of packages that gets installed with ghc. I want to know which packages are so intrinsic to GHC that you cannot install multiple versions of those packages even in a sandbox.
In other words, Which packages are not at all amenable to cabal sandbox?

Comment: Why in the world would someone vote to close because "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"? o_O

Answer (score 4):

If you run `ghc-pkg list`, there should be two lists of packages: those installed in `/usr/local/lib/ghc` (or wherever GHC is installed), and those in `~/.ghc/`. The packages in `/usr/local/lib/ghc` come with GHC.

Comment: on my machine there seem to be no packages in `/usr/local/lib/ghc` but they seem to be in `/var/lib/ghc/` and there seem to be a lot of packages in there. Even `GLUT-2.1.2.2` is there.

Comment: I guess it needs more explanation. I have edited the question.